# What is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, openfire

I'm running a [stress test](https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1232) on `Openfire` in an Amazon EC2, and after 28.000 of connections, my stress test resets and this errors appear to me.

What is it?

Comment: What? You connect quickly  to ec2 remote amazon service, and You would like to know, why they abort after 28.000 connections rapidly behind each other ? OpenFire-testcases seem to offer this to simulate heavy connection load. But does EC2 allow this ? Did You ask them ? It could have any reasons, and several of them are perhaps security related.

Answer (score 5):

In my understanding your machine runs out of available ports.

You can confirm that with count of sockets in TIME_WAIT:

```
netstat -a
```

If that is confirmed - you may consider to adjust tcp configuration, e.g. as pointed in: https://serverfault.com/questions/23385/huge-amount-of-time-wait-connections-says-netstat

Answer (score 3):

This error (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address) can come if lots of TCP/IP connection is present and your program cross the available port range at OS level.

Command to check the port range
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range

This can be avoid by fine tuning TCP socket parameters at OS level.

1. Increased the local port range using below command

   echo 1024 65000 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range.

   Be careful before changing this limit. I would suggest first to figure out why lots of TCP/IP connection is present. is there any connection leak in your program (connection is not closed after use)? If it is the valid case and your program really need lots of port for TCP/IP then only go and modify the limit.
2. Change the TCP_FIN_TIMEOUT using below command

   echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout

   This setting determines the time that must elapse before TCP/IP can release a closed connection and reuse its resources. By reducing the value of this entry, TCP/IP can release closed connections faster, making more resources available for new connections. Adjust this in the presence of many connections sitting in the TIME_WAIT state.

   Note:- This can be useful only when lots of TCP/IP connection is in CLOSE_WAIT state. 
   TCP/IP connection state can be determine by command - "netstat -a -n|grep -E "^(tcp)"| cut -c 68-|sort|uniq -c|sort -n".
3. Change the TCP_TW_REUSE using below command

   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse

   This allows reusing sockets in TIME_WAIT state for new connections when it is safe from protocol viewpoint. Default value is 0 (disabled). It is generally a safer alternative to tcp_tw_recycle

   Note: The tcp_tw_reuse setting is particularly useful in environments where numerous short connections are open and left in TIME_WAIT state, such as web servers. Reusing the sockets can be very effective in reducing server load.
4. Change the TCP_TW_RECYCLE using below command

   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle

   It enables fast recycling of TIME_WAIT sockets. The default value is 0 (disable).